# Can you use the modified value of a underscore chain before its finished?

Tags: underscore.js

I'm attempting to create a function that sorts a list of players and identifies the top 5 by score.

I'm running a few chained filters on an array and I'd like to be able to use the current state of the modified array after each step.

I'm currently achieving this in two chain steps but I'd like to it in one if possible:

```
var hilightTop5 = function( propName, aPlayers ) {

   var aSortedReversed = _.chain(aPlayers)
        .sortBy( function(player){ return player[propName] })
        .reverse()
        .value();

    var aTop5Map = _.chain(aSortedReversed)
        .map( function(player) {  
            player.top5 = ( player[propName] >= aSortedReversed[4][propName] ) ? 0 : 1; 
            return player; })   
        .value();

    return aTop5Map;
};
```

I'd like to do something like this and only use one chain:

```
    var hilightTop5 = function( propName, aPlayers ) {

       var aTop5Map = _.chain(aPlayers)
            .sortBy( function(player){ return player[propName] })
            .reverse()
            .map( function(player) {  
                var aCurrentStateTop5Map = aTop5Map.value(); // this.aTop5Map.value() ?!
                player.top5 = ( player[propName] >= aCurrentStateTop5Map[4][propName] ) ? 0 : 1; 
                return player; })   
            .value();


        return aTop5Map;
    };
```

Is that possible? To somehow use the state of the array after each filter step?

Comment: Well, have you tried it? Did you get errors?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data of the format you're using as well as the structure you're hoping to get out? Might make it easier to understand/ test in jsbin.com. Also the third argument given to map should be the current state of the array (function(player,index,collection)

Comment: sorry guys I actually didn't receive any email alerts for these comments - weird - I did just get an alert for the answer below so I'll test that in a jsfiddle with test data and get back to you - it's been awhile but I'd still like to know ;-D

Comment: ok it checks out - fiddle with test data provided in the comments of psquared's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the list value that underscore passes to the map iterator:

```
var hilightTop5 = function(sortProperty, players) {
    return _.chain(players)
        .sortBy(sortProperty)
        .reverse()
        .map(function(player, key, list) {
            player.top5 = (player[sortProperty] >= list[4][sortProperty]) ? 1 : 0;
            // Another possibility:
            // player.top5 = (key < 5) ? 1 : 0;
            return player;
        })
        .value();            
}
```

Comment: that's pretty powerful - nice job! I've tested it in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/headwinds/qc2sf/